# Server Sent Events on Cloud Run with IAP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, server-sent-events, google-iap

I've got a NodeJS API deployed to Cloud Run behind IAP for authentication. I'm trying to send SSEs to the client, but they are all buffering until they hit a max buffer length or the events are done and then they send.

It works locally and the events send immediately.  And in the deployed environment, I can see the Cloud Run logs that the API is triggering the writes immediately, but they don't arrive until later in batches.

I assume it has something to do with header stripping or something in the GFE or IAP, but I can't seem to get the events to send immediately. I've added the `"X-Accel-Buffering": "no"` but that didn't help.

EDIT - Cloud Run HTTP/2 is disabled because it currently loops infinitely when used with IAP.  Nothing I can find in the docs say that Cloud Run requires HTTP/2 for SSE.

Here's the deploy line:

```
gcloud run deploy api-XXXX 
--quiet 
--image us-east4-docker.pkg.dev/hq-xxxxx/XXXX 
--update-env-vars NODE_CONFIG_ENV=develop 
--update-labels managed-by=github-actions,commit-sha=XXX 
--platform managed 
--format json 
--region us-east4 
--project XXXX
--no-cpu-throttling
```

Current headers returned by API - thought I've tried many.

```
"Content-Type": "text/event-stream; charset=UTF-8",
"Cache-Control": "no-cache",
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"X-Accel-Buffering": "no",
```

Comment: Edit your post and include the deploy command. Did you enable HTTP/2 (--use-http2)? Does your container HTTP server software/code support HTTP/2?

Comment: Do not ignore problems like this: `loops infinitely when used with IAP`. Fix that first. For SSE, you are not required to use HTTP/2 but I would not deploy without it. HTTP 1.1 imposes many limitations on SSE. The choice is yours. Constantly chase problems or build and deploy correctly.

Comment: @JohnHanley The loop issue is on the google side.  It’s a known bug.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Do you have a link? However, as a test, disable IAP and test with HTTP/2 enabled. At least you will know if that resolves that part of your problem.

Comment: @JohnHanley  I figured it out... it wasn't a header, but the response code.  Answer added below.  And here's the not on the IAP infinite loop: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-cloud-run#known_limitations

Answer (score 1):

Default status code for a POST in most frameworks is 201.  If you submit a body and expect a SSE response, you should modify the status code to 200.
Google Cloud Run will buffer the entire response if the status is not 200.

In sum: ensure that your "success" response code is always 200 when sending `text/event-stream` / server sent events.

Comment: This answer is helpful. I cannot find an SSE spec that specifies 200 is required. I can find other sources that mention this [link](https://www.pubnub.com/guides/server-sent-events/) and [link](https://sysmgt.lenovofiles.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Ftsm%2Fserver_sent_events.html).